# table-of-content div in wrong position when exporting with org-mode

Tags: emacs, org-mode, bibtex

**Environment:** Ubuntu 12.04 32bit. Emacs 24 with built-in org-mode.
 Reproduced on another `ubuntu 12.04` with almost identical emacs configuration (home notebook).
Setup as in: http://www.mail-archive.com/emacs-orgmode@gnu.org/msg11528.html

**Objective:** use `\cite{}` in .org and export to html.

```
#+TITLE: bug

#+LINK: bib file:bibref.bib::%s

#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: bibref plain limit:t

* Heading
Table of content position in exported html is wrong. \cite{Yang2012}
```

In the html export, the `table-of-content` div was inserted into some other block, which often messed up the display. Has anyone noticed the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

org mode allows direct control over the location of table of contents as in http://orgmode.org/manual/Table-of-contents.html. Simply insert [TABLE-OF-CONTENTS] before the first heading.